# Not able to launch WiFi in Ubuntu 16.04 with RTL8723DE

Tags: 16.04, wireless

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 recently alongside Windows 10.

Here is an image of the terminal after executing the instruction `lspci -nnk | grep -A3 -Fe '[0280]'; rfkill list`

[image: Terminal image]

The kernel version is `4.13.0-32-generic`

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of the terminal command `lspci -nnk | grep -A3 -Fe '[0280]'; rfkill list`? Thanks.

Comment: What is your kernel version? Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `uname -r`

Comment: With respect to the possible duplicate, Dinesh needs the branch for kernel versions 4.11 and higher.

Answer (score 0):

With a temporary working internet connection, open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install build-essential dkms git
git clone -b 4.11-up https://github.com/jeremyb31/rtl8723de.git
sudo dkms add ./rtl8723de
sudo dkms build rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414
sudo dkms install rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414
sudo modprobe rtl8723de
```

Reboot and your wireless should be working.

Comment: I executed the above instruction. Every instruction executed without any error and rebooted the system as well. still wireless is not working.

Comment: I installed OS again and tried. Still, it is not working. 

What is duplicate here in the below discussion.
"With respect to the possible duplicate, Dinesh needs the branch for kernel versions 4.11 and higher. – chili555"

Comment: Did the module load? Check: `lsmod | grep rtl` If it did not load, please try: `sudo modprobe rtl8723de` Is the airplane mode switch on or off? `rfkill list all`

Comment: lsmod | grep rtl
Terminal Result
btrtl                  16384  1 btusb
bluetooth             544768  12 btrtl,btintel,bnep,btbcm,btusb

sudo modprobe rtl8723de
Terminal result
modprobe: FATAL: Module rtl8723de not found in directory /lib/modules/4.13.0-32-generic

Comment: Please see my edited answer. I am sorry that I omitted the 'install' step.

Comment: Fortunately, WiFi is working now. 
Because, Today when I connected my machine to network via LAN cable. It asked for an update, after that WiFi is working now.
Thanks for the help.